# Visualizing a SQL query in Carto

Tags: coordinate-system, carto, sql

I'm new to SQL.
I wrote a query to perform a join based on a common attribute. I am having problems displaying it because the column `the_geom_webmercator` doesn't exist.

My question is, is my table produced after the join a "view", is it a new table I can modify? It might be important to note I am bringing in data from a PostGIS db via enterprise. Reading through the documentation it seems I should just add a new column for `the_geom_webmercator` and populate it with the information from `the_geom.` How can I do this?

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT
  id, name, region_id, phone_number, feature_order, cartodb_id, latitude, 
longitude, addressable_type,
  ST_SetSRID(    ST_MakePoint(
      longitude,
      latitude
    ),
    4326
  ) AS the_geom

FROM (SELECT 
_d.id, _d.name, _d.region_id, _d.phone_number, 
_d.feature_order, _add.cartodb_id, _add.latitude, _add.longitude, 
_add.addressable_type, _add.the_geom


FROM addresses AS _add
JOIN places AS _d ON _d.id = _add.addressable_id

WHERE _d.open = 'true'  AND _add.addressable_type = 'store'

) AS _camshaft_georeference_long_lat_analysis
```

Comment: @ramiroaznar Thanks a bunch! This worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [PostGIS ST_Transform function](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html), you can use something like this:

```
WITH query AS (...)
SELECT 
   *, 
   ST_Transfrom(the_geom, 3857) as the_geom_webmercator 
FROM 
  query
```